# Tracing LINQ TO SQL generated queries in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, linq, linq-to-sql, debugging

Quick question on LINQ to SQL generated queries output.

I am in a ASP.NET MVC project, Visual Studio 2008, and I am trying what's suggested in MSDN documentation:

```
MyDataContext _dc = new MyDataContext();
_dc.Log = Console.Out;
```

But nothing is being shown on "Output" window (CTRL+Alt+O).

Is there is something else I need to configure in order to make LINQ to SQL dumping debug info to Output window in Visual Studio 2008?

I don't know if it makes any difference, but my entities (and **MyDataContext** class) are located in a separate *class library* project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [LINQ to SQL Visualizer](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx). Attach the debugger, add a breakpoint and you'll be able to use it.