# How to view LINQ Generated SQL statements on insert?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

How do I view the SQL generated by linq on insert statement ?

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                db.tblCameras.InsertOnSubmit(new tblCamera() {
                    CameraID=textbox1.Text,
                    IPAddress=textbox2.Text,
                });
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
```

**i'm planning to execute generated sql on another copy of this db , i have tried to use**

> db.Log = Console.Out;

but this generated is not useful in my case

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblCamera]([CameraID], [IPAddress])
VALUES (@p0, @p1)
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [14]
-- @p1: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.6.1586.0
```

any suggestion!

Comment: You might want to check out the answer in this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850024/tracing-linq-to-sql-generated-queries-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @IsThatQueeblo i need to do same thing but by code, i need the full sql generated query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view LINQ Generated SQL statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899974/how-to-view-linq-generated-sql-statements)

Comment: @Lightwalker the previous link using db.Log and it's not useful in my case, thanks.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are using Linq2Sql, not EntitiyFramework?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes i'm using LINQ2SQL

Answer (score 1):

You should try to catch the query with SQL Profiler, and you can easily copy/paste the SQL query from there.

Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/library/ms175047.aspx